For a specific API (eg Google Maps Javascript API), how to found the number of request failure due to a quota limit exceeded
The appropriated tool seems to be the metric explorer (https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer), I am able to filter by service for selecting only the Google Maps Javascript Api: "service = maps-backend.googleapis.com" but I don't know how to find the good metric.
The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/docs/quotas/set-up-quota-alerts) mentions a "Consumer Quota" > "Quota exceeded error" metric. Under "Consumer Quota", I only have Allocation Quota usage, Concurrent Quota limit, Concurrent Quota Usage, Quota Limit and Rate Quota Usage... None of them seems to be the equivalent of "Quota exceeded error"...

When you're using Cloud Console, you'll want to uncheck "Active" on the list of metrics in order to have non-active metrics (including perhaps serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/exceeded) enumerated.

See Alerting on quota exceeded which references this metric too.

Thanks, I am now able to see quota exceedings, but only in percentage. I think this is the only possible return for the metric calculation.
I also checked the log explorer to see if I am able to create a new metric based on the errors, but the quota exceeded errors from Google Maps are not in the logs.

For the moment, I will stay with crossing the quota exceeded error metric and the 4xx error from the Google Cloud API page for Google Maps (quota exceeded errors return a 413).

In the Metric select: removing the "active" filter then selecting "Quota exceeded error" then modifying directly the MQL request to

fetch consumer_quota | metric
'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/exceeded'

gives the number of exceedings
